# Creating reusable iOS "views" (how to size?)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have looked at other questions on this site and managed to create a "View" with a xib in the interface builder which I can use inside another View successfully.

What I don't understand is, the View I am building to be reusable is how I position the controls in that view?

When I then use the View inside another View and position it as 0, 0 which should be the top left. It doesn't go to the top left because the reusable View itself is positioned differently. Is this normal? How do I make the control wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create subView with controls as it have to look in the subView lets say

You have subview call it as view1 like below and X as controls inside it

> ```
>      -------------
>     |             |
>     |  X    X     |
>     |  X    X     |
>      -------------
> ```

And you have view2 like

> ```
>        -------------
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>        -------------
> ```

Now if you want to place above view1 to view2 at the top it will look like

> ```
>        -------------
>       |             |
>       |   X    X    |
>       |   X    X    |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>        -------------
> ```

and if you place view1 in view 2 at bottom it will look like

> ```
>        -------------
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |             |
>       |   X    X    |
>       |   X    X    |
>        -------------
> ```

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you mean with the positioning. Are you saying position the view how you want it to look like?

Comment: Yes, you need to position the subview in the superview how you want to look it in the superview. If you want to see controls at the bottom of the superview you need to put subview at the bottom of the superview